# .md file screenshot is not rendering but linking is working

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I am creating .md files in my folders. When writing this and clicking on the link, it directs me to the image.

```
[screenshot](..\\screenshots\\screenshot1.png)
```

While this is directing me to the image, this is not showing the image on the .md file but it shows the error window symbol.

```
![screenshot](..\\screenshots\\screenshot1.png)
```

As I know, adding "!" to the beginning should convert the linking to the image rendering but there is a problem here. What am I doing wrong? Right now, the .md file and the image file are on my local folder, not Github.

Extra information: If I put the screenshots folder to the .md path, the images are shown successfully. If the screenshots folder is 1 folder above and I use "..", the images give an error but the linking to the file still works.

Comment: Can you use code blocks in the editor, and post the code exactly the way you use it in reality?

Comment: It looks like you're using backward slashes, but GitHub uses `/` in paths.

Comment: @BenjaminW. When I use / instead of \, nothing is changed. Right now, this is on my local folder, not Github.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you for your reply. i also edited the question as you suggested

Comment: You use `..\\ `, two periods, and two backslashes?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried with {/} instead of {\\} and the same problem is going on. When I do not use {!}, it successfully links to the file. When I use {!}, the image is not shown. I also added one more piece of information to the end of the question. Maybe it means something

Comment: take his absolute path for testing and not his realtive path.